# How to interpret curl timeouts?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, bash-scripting

```
curl --max-time 3 'http://website.com';
  if [ 0 -eq $? ]; then 
    ...
  else
    ...
  fi
```

I'm trying to have curl respond differently to URL's that timeout. How do I pass the output of the curl failure into the if statement? This just simply is not working:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124918/how-to-check-whether-a-command-such-as-curl-completed-without-error

Answer (score 0):

`curl` exit codes (the value of `$?`) are documented in its manpage.  An exit code of 28 corresponds to "*Operation timeout. The specified  time-out  period  was  reached according to the conditions.*"